# Update Sqlite database from checkboxes

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a group of checkboxes in which I want to add their "checked" status to the database.
I used to add them to a localStorage like this:

```
    function SaveData()
    {
        var status = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter('.custom').map(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name'); 
        var CheckBoxId= $(this).attr('CheckboxId');                                            
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        return { 'name':name, 'status' : 'Checked', 'CheckBoxId':CheckBoxId}; 
        else
        return null;
        });
        localStorage["Days"] = status.length;

        for(var i = 0;i<status.length;i++)
        {

            localStorage["Day" + i] = status[i].name;


        }
    }
```

Now I want to add them to the sqlite database but when I add any statements like here, the javascript page is not seen at all, so I don't know where should I write the statement.

```
       for(var i = 0;i<status.length;i++)
        {
           tx.executeSql('UPDATE WeekDay SET Checked = 1 Where WeekId= status[i].CheckBoxId');  

        }
```

This is the table at the database:

```
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WeekDay');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WeekDay (id unique, DayName, Checked INTEGER)');
```

Is there some method to work on the database from within the functions themselves ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE WeekDay SET Checked = 1 Where WeekId= ?', [status[i].CheckBoxId]);
```

You can't directly reference the variable from the query, you have to insert its value.